# Why does a named pipe not get deleted after system restart?

Tags: pipe, fifo

As far as I understand, named pipes are not written to disk but are stored in memory. Here's how I created a named pipe -

```
$ mkfifo pipe21
$ grep "simple" SimpleDoc.txt > pipe21 &
[1] 2775
$ cat pipe21
Very simple doc that contains plaintext. 
[1]+  Done                    grep --color=auto "simple" SimpleDoc.txt > pipe21
```

After this, I restarted my system. However, even after the restart, I see pipe21 in my current directory. Why is that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No they're written to disk. The command `mkfifo pipe21` creates the corresponding device on your filesystem. Often times these devices are kept under `/dev` but named pipes (aka. FIFOS) don't necessarily have to be kept in this directory.

*excerpt from wikipedia article*

> The named pipe can be deleted just like any file:
>       `$ rm my_pipe`

#### Example

Make a FIFO:

```
$ pwd
/home/saml

$ mkfifo pipe21
```

Check out the FIFO device:

```
$ ls -l | grep pipe
prw-rw-r--   1 saml saml        0 Jul 24 12:22 pipe21

$ file pipe21 
pipe21: fifo (named pipe)
```

Delete the device:

```
$ rm pipe21 

$ ls -l | grep pipe
```

#### References

- [Named Pipes - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe)

Comment: `/dev` does not have to contain all of the devices on the system -- it is perfectly legal to have them elsewhere.

Comment: @ChrisDown - thanks I forgot that they can be created in other directories such as /tmp or where ever else. Updated my answer, thanks again for the feedback!

Answer (score 12):

A named pipe is part of the filesystem. Anything that has a filename is part of the filesystem. If that happens to be a filesystem in persistent storage (i.e. on disk), then it survives a system reboot.

A filesystem entry for a named pipe just has a name, the usual metadata (time, permissions, etc.), and a flag that says “this is a named pipe”. The data that goes through the pipe doesn't go to the filesystem. But the named pipe itself is in the filesystem.